# is there a difference between Datetime.civil and Datetime.new in ruby?

Tags: ruby

Hello i've been searching in the internet and seeing that there are many aliases for ruby methods doing the same (i don't know why)
so i'm confused, is there a difference between Datetime.civil and Datetime.new in ruby ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-civil), they are the same.
Also:

```
DateTime.method(:new) == DateTime.method(:civil)
=> true
```

Comment: interesting... so that's the way you compare methods ? thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The calendar date is a particular day of a calendar year, identified by its ordinal number within a calendar month within that year.

In those classes, this is so-called “civil”.

Please look in to this .. http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html